# how can I get all data in one column?

Tags: codeigniter

[this is the actual I want to expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z10Ud.png)I want to get all the fees in one column, I have 5 fees but only one fee are appending

```
                    foreach ($client_class->getLoanFeesInfoById($li_id) as $row_d){ 
                            $fee_id = $row_d->fee_id;

                                 foreach ($fees_class->getInfoByFeeId($fee_id) as $row_e) 
                                    {
                                         $fee_name = $row_e->fee_name;      
                                         $default_amount = $row_e->manual_default_amount;

                                         $disbursement_amount = $loan_amount - $default_amount;
                                    }
                            }


                        echo "<tr>

                                <td>".number_format($default_amount)."-".$fee_name."</td>
                                <td>".$deposit_code."</td>
                                <td>P".number_format($disbursement_amount)."</td>

                            </tr>";
```

Comment: you need to provide sample output of the arrays as well as what you expect the final solution to look like as an addition to your question. it is currently unclear although I have my suspicions as to the problem.

Comment: I put an image to view my expected output

Comment: and the other half?

Comment: how can i get the value of the one I echo in uper part to put on may table

Comment: i meant you've provided the expected output, now what is the output of the arrays `$fees_class->getInfoByFeeId($fee_id)` and `$client_class->getLoanFeesInfoById($li_id)`

Answer (score 0):

When you echo `<td>".number_format($default_amount)."-".$fee_name."</td>`, you will only get the last values that have been obtained in the `foreach`. So as a solution you can use a variable inside the inner `foreach` to store all the fee.

```
$fee = '';
foreach ($fees_class->getInfoByFeeId($fee_id) as $row_e) 
{
    $fee_name = $row_e->fee_name;      
    $default_amount = $row_e->manual_default_amount;
    $disbursement_amount = $loan_amount - $default_amount;
    $fee .= number_format($default_amount)."-".$fee_name."<br/>";
}
```

Then you can echo as
`<td>".$fee."</td>`